# how to load service on window load in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that should load on page refresh how to load this service on window load.

```
modules.ts

    import { _someService, _cmOffService, MenuController } from './some.directive';
    
    const menuModule = angular.module('menuModule', [])
    .factory('someService', _someService)
    .factory('cmOffService', _cmOffService)
    .controller('MenuController', MenuController);

directive.ts

    _cmOffService.$inject = ["canvasMenu", "$rootScope"];

    alert("outside function") //It does alert

    export function _cmOffService(canvasMenu, $rootScope) {
        alert("calling this") //Does not work
        $rootScope.$on(TOGGLE_OFF, someFunction);
    
        return {
            someFunction: someFunction,
        };
    }
```

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Inject it into some main app controller?

Comment: updated the question already into the controller please check

Comment: Your update shows the service being provided. It doesn’t show it actually being injected.

Comment: Strange _cmOffService does not have alert but out side _cmOffService function it does alert Yes in same controller it being injected any reason